# Get a task list with their total GDI/User handles in Windows cmd

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I would like to get the total GDI/User handles for each running process.

I've found how this can be done in powershell using `GET-PROCESS` but I can't find how to do this in `cmd`.

Is it possible to get a list of tasks and their handles using `cmd` in Windows?

Comment: CMD is just a shell. Use Process Hacker or Process Explorer to get those details.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Are these are separate apps that would require installing? The reason I specified `cmd` is that I need to run commands in Java to get this information for debugging purposes. We can't install anything extra on the users pc so I was hoping there were cmd commands that could provide this information.

Comment: If you are dealing with programming stuffs StackOverflow is the right place to ask.

Comment: @Biswapriyo This isn't a programming question. This is asking if it is possible using the command prompt in windows. What I'm using to run the command is irrelevant. The equivalent would be me saying I can't install 3rd party apps, can I do this in command prompt.